# Динамическая загрузка библиотек в Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Я хочу использовать динамическую загрузку библиотек в Android проекте. Согласно документации NDK, я могу использовать для этого функции `dlopen`, `dlsym`, `dlclose`, если подключу библиотеку *libdl.so*. Я использую это в проекте, но `dlopen` возвращает ошибку:

> dlopen filed: "libstdc++.so.6" not found

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Я получил ответ на вопрос [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592218/android-ndk-and-dynamic-load-library-with-dlopen)